# How to delete a key from Firebase using golang?

Tags: go, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

this is my Firebase structure.

```
Contacts

{
  "-Kav_cy_EFZnu5vNWP2g" :

 {

    "Address" : "dfsswrfdssddsd",
    "CurrentDate" : 1484910921411,
    "Email" : "a@fg.hh",
    "Name" : "abc",
    "PhoneNumber" : "53465465765677",
    "State" : "fdsf",
    "Status" : "Completed",
    "Zipcode" : "43434"
  },


  "-Kb9ghONh670tUOkOG3N" :

 {


    "Address" : "jfhjhfjfj",
    "CurrentDate" : 1485164432603,
    "Email" : "fg@gmail.com",
    "Name" : "dcf",
    "PhoneNumber" : "9897878787",
    "State" : "fdsf",
    "Status" : "Completed",
    "Zipcode" : "56546"


  }
}
```

i want to delete data corresponding to the key(`-Kav_cy_EFZnu5vNWP2g`). I have tried below code, but it's not working:

model

```
func (m *User) DeleteFromDB(ctx context.Context,key string)(bool)  {


    dB, err := GetFirebaseClient(ctx,"")
    if err!=nil{
        log.Println("Connection error:",err)
    }
    err = dB.Child(key).remove();
    if err!=nil{
        log.Println("Deletion error:",err)
        return false
    }
 return true


}
```

in `DeleteFromDB()`, I have the key.

Comment: What Firebase client are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try changing the remove function like this

```
dB.Child("/Contacts/"+key).Remove()
```